# CSS3 checked not loading selectivizr in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, checked

I am using selectivizr.js to resolve IE8 issue with "checked" option. But, I am unable to load the script written for it when I add checked option dynamically. How do I resolve this?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [selectivizr.com](http://selectivizr.com/):

> The emulation is not dynamic. Once the styles are applied they are fixed so changes to the DOM won't be reflected.

So I'm guessing you need to re-run selectivizr.js when the DOM is changed. It's not yet supported as far as I can see, but [this pull request](https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/pull/75) might do the trick?